# Which type of classification system should i use?

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I need to train a classifier on motion pattern data from an accelerometer. For each time sample I stored the X Y and Z coordinates. Thus a single movement is represented in my dataset like so:

```
[0.39028051 -0.5483283  10.385374]; [0.17420317 -0.2802931  10.72625]; [0.28956637  -0.13387422 11.9645]; [0.6281768    -0.14725612 13.369692]; [0.72674876 -0.115191355    14.50422]; [0.7450281   -0.079684645    15.090715]; [0.74526054 -0.44727635 15.027773]; [0.6936915  -0.9639046  14.088198]; [0.5290651  -1.1378883  12.5164585]; [0.23881127    -1.346372   10.889902]; [0.052466527    -1.2700776  9.227933]; [0.019615699 -0.8237766  7.65959]; [0.10373996   -0.29147366 6.416745]; [0.17365126  0.09419979  5.420801]; [0.18465124  0.3646446   4.5289593]; [0.22039331 0.52677184  3.8076568]; [0.33365434 0.48184758  3.4170833]; [0.40346703 0.21976978  3.472282];
```

where the values between [] represent the XYZ components.

At first i thought that a Hidden Markov Model would best fit my problem. But i'm having troubles defining the states in my data. All examples i find have a clear defined, finite set of states (i.e. rain, sunny or cloudy). All values in my dataset are in between -11 and +11, but they're not integers obviously. Still, could i use this as states? thus giving me 11 * 11 * 11 = 1331 states? And how would i calculate the transition matrix?

Furthermore the number of observation differ between movement (although belonging to the same class).

I'm sorry i this question is too broad, a pointer to a tutorial on HMM's with this type of data also helps a lot!

Thanks

Comment: you're exposing a possible solution (HMM) instead of defining the problem. what do you have to do with your data, exactly?

Comment: this document may help: http://webspace.ulbsibiu.ro/arpad.gellert/html/SIC_HMM.pdf

Comment: I need to classify head movements into 10 different classes which are all basically shake or nod movement. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I think it would be easier to compute the delta between each two coords tuple and after enought deltas have been collected an algorithm may find if the entire movement is a shake, a nod, or neither

Comment: This would reduce dimensionality of the data to a sequence of floats. But it still puzzles me how i can determine the number of states.

Answer (score 0):

in pseudocode, compute all the distances between two points:

```
for index=0 to coords.length() step 2 
{
   x1=coord[i].x
   y1=coord[i].y
   z1=coord[i].z

   x2=coord[i+1].x
   y2=coord[i+1].y
   z2=coord[i+1].z

   deltaX = x2-x1
   deltaY = y2-y1
   deltaZ = z2-z1
   distance[i] = SquareRoot(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY + deltaZ*deltaZ)
}
```

Then you can compute a Gaussian distribution on the `distance` values, and also the mean, the median, the variance... An algorithm shouldn't be too complicate to write, even if it may need some adjustment here and there.

Or, another method, within the loop you can easily compute the difference between the current and the previous distance:

```
previousDistance = distance
distance = SquareRoot(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY + deltaZ*deltaZ)
diff = distance - previousDistance
```

And then apply a [high pass filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-pass_filter) on `diff`.